# How to change the MS App Id on a bot?

Tags: botframework

It's not possible to change the MS app id on a bot, but we need this to manage the link between bots and Azure AD v2 Apps.

I would have logged this as a feature request, but where? Can you setup a uservoice or more direct line of support.

Comment: BotFramework UserVoice: https://botframework.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 1):

Is recreating the bot out of the question? You can get a new ID that way. You can log issues/bugs/enhancements here https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder